# Xuggler: IContainer.open() blocks

Tags: java, mp4, xuggler, xuggle

I am trying to open a video file with xuggle like this:

```
    if (container.open(in,  null) < 0) {  
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: ");
    }
```

The problem happened when i use mp4 file and i passed to open a InputStream:

```
       InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
```

In this case IContainer.open remains blocked and does not return anything.
However if I pass a file name to the open method or I use the flv format, it works fine.
I have to use InputStream with an mp4 file.
Can someone help me to find the problem?

Comment: If you found a solution to this, could you please update it here? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 3):

In case some other person runs across this issue, I'll say what I did that fixed my problem:
Instead of opening from an `InputStream`, I opened the file directly used

```
if (container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0)
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not open file: " + filename);
}
```

I hope this helps somebody that encounters this problem later. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use InputOutputStreamHandler
e.g.

```
File initialFile = new File(filename);
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
        InputOutputStreamHandler handler = new InputOutputStreamHandler(is);
        int result = container.open(handler, IContainer.Type.READ, null);
        if (result < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: "
                    + filename);
```